# Running JMeter without disabling the Firewall

Tags: jmeter

I'm asked to run JMeter without disablng the Firewall.

How can we pass the ports used by JMeter to pass through the Firewall,without disabling it.

Comment: Will need more details like, What error is being shown in jmeter? and is ssl being used? is so what is the config?

Comment: I have still not run JMeter with Firewall enabled. I have not used SSL so far.         Im asked to see if we can run Jmeter without disabling Firewall and how

Comment: is it API or website that you are trying to load test on? in any of the case you if you can call the endpoints or open the website from browser with firewall on the you should be able to do it using jmeter, I would suggest that you give it a try once

Comment: Its a web app created by my office

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running JMeter in [distributed mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) you need to open the following ports:

- the port you define as `server_port`, by default 1099
- the port you define as `server.rmi.localport`
- the ports you define as `client.rmi.localport`

So you need to come up with the list of ports which are available and not being used by other applications and configure JMeter to use these ports. Once done you can open the ports in the firewall.

More information:

- [Using a different port](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#portchange)
- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)